# "Нам любые дороги дороги..."

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Вспомнилась знаменитая песенка из "Бременских музыкантов" и подумалось: слова "дорог" и "дорога" так похожи. Они наверняка родственные, но как это может быть? Значения-то разные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Они совсем не родственны.

дорога:
Ближайшая этимология: I., укр. доро'га, блр. даро'га, сербск.-цслав. драга "долина", сербохорв. дра?га, словен. dra'ga "овраг, лощина", др.-чеш. draґha "дорога", польск. droga "дорога", в.-луж. dro'ha "след, дорога, улица", н.-луж. droga "улица".

дорогой:
Ближайшая этимология: до'рог, дорога', до'рого, укр. дороги'й, ст.-слав. драгъ, болг. драг, сербохорв. дра?г, дра'га, словен. dra?g, чеш., слвц. drahy', польск. drogi, в.-луж. drohi, н.-луж. drogi.

Первое Фасмер возводит к "дергать", полагая, что "дорога" изначально означало **продранное** в лесу пространство.

Второе - от общеславянского "drag", восходящего к индоевропейскому морфу с разными (в т.ч. современными) значениями из области экономики: быть значимым, существенным и даже "нанимать" (работника).